# How to reconnect after MySQL Server gone away error

Tags: 7, database

I have long running CLI script which crashes down sometimes because of:

> MySQL Server gone away

```
#inside loop
$content = null;
while ($content == null) {
  try {
     $content = getContentFromMysql();
   } catch(PDOException $ex) {
     #What to do here?
   }  
}
#do something long with fetched content
```

What should I write in the catch clause? (I am using standard Drupal DB API)

**EDIT**

Since error happens when I try to select data I write my own wrapper class (I am using MSSQL as main db, so I can messed up Mysql driver):

```
class JoomlaDatabaseConnection_mysql extends DatabaseConnection_mysql {
    public function select($table, $alias = null, $options = null) {
        self::openConnection('joomla', 'default');
        return parent::select($table, $alias, $options);       
    }     
}
```

But know how to tell Drupal to use this class?

:/

> final protected static function openConnection($key, $target)

shame not public, but I understand why.

---

Thanks to @karthik advice I am testing solution with `ini_set`.

Another solution for altering database access class is to create new driver:

- Create directory of driver name (e.g. mysqlJoomla) in includes/database
- copy standard mysql driver files from includes/database/mysql
- change database.inc file content to e.g.:

  ```
  class DatabaseConnection_mysqlJoomla extends DatabaseConnection_mysql {
   public function select($table, $alias = null, $options = null) {
      parent::openConnection('joomla', 'default');
      return parent::select($table, $alias, $options);
   }     
  }
  ```
- add new driver info:

  ```
  $joomla_url = array(
   'database' => JDB,
   'username' => JUSER,
   'password' => JPASS,
   'host' => JHOST,
   'prefix' => 'jos_',
   'driver' => 'mysqlJoomla',
  );
  Database::addConnectionInfo('joomla', 'default', $joomla_url);
  ```

**EDIT**

Oops I see I can't use

> openConnection

method inside driver class because it is method from Database class :/

It is a big problem in DB API. Programmer should has chance to reconnect (calling openConnection()) by using inheritance.

Comment: You can try setting the default timeout to a higher value see this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644432/mysql-server-has-gone-away-in-exactly-60-seconds

Comment: @karthik unfortunately this issue is on MySQL side

Comment: You are asking two different questions: why you get a "server gone away" error, and how to override a database driver to rewrite one of its methods. Notice that a database driver is written when it is necessary to use a different database engine, not to change the default connection used for a query.